# change log4j Logging level from INFO to DEBUG

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, log4j

In my java code, the following line

```
getHibernateTemplate().save(billingCompany);
```

is printing a logger message

> 2013-11-11 14:05:20,962 **INFO**  [STDOUT] Hibernate: insert into
>   billing_log_company (COMPANY_ID, BILLING_LOG_ID) values (?, ?)

But actually I need DEBUG in place of INFO like this:

> 2013-11-11 14:05:20,962 **DEBUG** [STDOUT] Hibernate: insert into
>   billing_log_company (COMPANY_ID, BILLING_LOG_ID) values (?, ?)

I mean that we are not writing logger.info. logger.debug etc..
getHibernateTemplate().save(billingCompany) is printing that logger msg in INFO mode.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate messages it self is in hibernate source code, you can't change that. However, you can change Hibernate log level to `warn` or `debug`. but this will fill your console with a lot of logs

In your log properties file change

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info
```

to

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=debug
```

or

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=warn
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question. If you want `DEBUG` rather than `INFO` in the spring hibernate template then you'll have to change their source code. If you want to use `DEBUG` in our own code, just use

> logger.debug(...)

Answer (score 0):

Benjamin was clear in his approach.

You must be using some api to log like log4j, promatter...
most logger api has different methods for logging different scenarios.

Take log4j for example,

```
static Logger loggerfile = Logger.getLogger(ThisClass.class.getName());//creating logger instance
loggerFile.debug("debug");
loggerFile.info("info");
loggerFile.error("erre");
```